# exported library hook with QWidget::find() doesn't working

Tags: c#, c++, qt, hook, detours

I have a QT hook.dll library which injected in 3rd party application with detours.dll.
And if i adding QWidget::find() method to hook.cpp, then i getting DllNotFoundException in process of installing this hook.
Else if i don't add QWidget::find() into .cpp, then hook establish normally.
Hook building with QT 4.7.1 with VS2008

Please help, i was tormented with this bug 2 days:(

Answer (score 0):

solved. I opened hook.dll by Dependency Walker. And it check all deps. Well i just needed to place QTCore and QTGUI libraries to same folder with hook.dll.